# Openstack Magnum 12.0.0 Package In Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: openstack, cloud

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and trying to install openstack magnum from cloud-archive:wallaby repo. The problem is the deb package in repo does not have all the changes that has been commit in stable/wallaby.

https://opendev.org/openstack/magnum/src/branch/stable/wallaby

The deployment of clusters are getting failed because the package in repo does not have all the committed changes.

I have checked by downloading stable/wallaby branch packages of magnum it works fine.

I think the packages need to be updated in ubuntu cloud repo.

http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/magnum/

- Ammad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software).

Answer (score 0):

Fixes for stable releases of Ubuntu and the Ubuntu Cloud Archive must go through the Stable Release Updates (SRU) process [1]. There isn't an exception to pick up stable point releases of magnum, however individual fixes can be picked up as part of the SRU process.

For bugs related to OpenStack a good place to start is by opening a bug against the cloud archive here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-archive/ (you can also open bugs at [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/\](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/%5C)<project>). Someone will need to commit to testing/verifying any fixes once they are available as well. Also, it is not required, but greatly appreciated if debdiff patches can be contributed to bugs.

Thank you,
Corey

[1] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates